# Combination of how to write an equation

Tags: python, combinations

I want to find all possible combination of signs of a given equation, e.g. Input (q,p1).
Output: -p1+q, p1+q, p1-q, -p1 -q.

Does anybody know how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the product function (from itertools) to create the sign combinations and concatenate them to the terms using zip and join:

```
from itertools import product
terms = ["p","q1"]
opers = product(*["+-"]*len(terms))
formulas = ["".join(o+t for o,t in zip(op,terms)).strip("+") for op in opers]

print(formulas)
# ['p+q1', 'p-q1', '-p+q1', '-p-q1']
```